# Java Build Path and the cleaning up of unwanted debris

Tags: android, androidplot

In the course of my endevours I added two versions of androidplot to my project. I realised it is causing conflict so I tried removing both to start again and I am now getting

```
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity         ComponentInfo{com.cpdsessions.exercise_app/com.cpdsessions.exercise_app.ActivityLevelView}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1872)
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:250)
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1742)
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    at com.cpdsessions.exercise_app.ActivityLevelView.onCreate(ActivityLevelView.java:28)
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    ... 11 more
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.cpdsessions.exercise_app-1.apk]
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
02-11 22:50:10.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20299):    ... 20 more
```

Can anyone tell me how to clean this up please?

Comment: What's the name of the remaining Androidplot jar in your libs dir?

Answer (score 0):

I realised what the issue was here, I still had a androidplot element in my layout, so in fact the project wasn't fully cleaned of the attempt

Thanks